# Error on SQL Server tables while performing a join

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to perform a join between 4 tables  **schedule table, employee table, machine table and plate table.**

Problem is, at schedule table its primary key is a date while on the rest of the table have their primary key as char. I'm trying to convert the primary key in table into char to make it the same as the one on the others but I don't know how. Here is what I have done so far

```
create table Machine
(
    MachineID char(5),
    MachineType varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    MachineStatus varchar(10)NOT NULL
)

create table Employee
(
    EmployeeID char(5) Primary Key,
    EmployeeName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
)

create table Plate
(
    PlateID char(5) Primary Key,
    PlateModel varchar(30) NOT NULL,
)

create table MachineSchedule
(
    DateSchedule date Primary Key,
)
```

here is my join

```
SELECT Employee.EmployeName, Plate.PlateModel, Machine.MachineID, Machine.MachineType, Machine.MachineStatus
FROM Employee, Plate, Machine
JOIN MachineSchedule
ON MachineSchedule.DateSchedule=Machine.MachineID;
```

and here is the error it gave **Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.**

Comment: Are the table definitions you posted really complete? Don't you have a MachineID column in the MachineSchedule table perhaps?

Comment: MachineSchedule.DateSchedule is of type date, but Machine.MachineID is of type char(5). You cannot check for the equality of a date and a character string. What is the format of ID?

Comment: Add a machineID to the MachineSchedule table.

Comment: How are you cramming a date value into 5 characters and then calling it `MachineID`? Doesn't make sense. If you're using a special date encoding you'll have to incorporate that into the logic also. More likely though, judging by the names, none of these tables appear to relate to each other in a meaningful way in the first place.

Comment: So I should change the DateSchedule the same as other ID? I just started studying sql on my class and this is the basics they gave me actually. For the join stuff I though when joining the ID would be called from the other tables that's why I didn't make thr machine ID into the machine schedule.

Answer (score 0):

The table design and it's relation are not done properly. Based on this design and relation the simplest solution,i mean the query to make error free:

```
DROP TABLE [MachineSchedule];
```

Create The table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MachineSchedule](
    [DateSchedule] [date] NOT NULL,
    [MachineID] [char](5) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DateSchedule] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Changed Query

```
SELECT Employee.EmployeeName, Plate.PlateModel, Machine.MachineID, Machine.MachineType, Machine.MachineStatus
FROM Employee, Plate, Machine
JOIN MachineSchedule
ON MachineSchedule.MachineID = Machine.MachineID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Table structure is incorrect, you should use integer datatype for primary key   not char or datetime  as its creates indexing and we can not join table on char and date datatype they never have same value; and lastly where is the join for other tables in from clause. there should be join condition for  Employee, Plate, Machine.

and primary and foreign key constraints also missing

Answer (score 0):

You think
Date column=char column ?

Use with conver to char 
For example

On
cast(m.id as char(20))=ma.id
Or update column type